# How do I create an arrayformula to calculate the median of three different values from one row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, median

How do you create an arrayformula to calculate the median of three different values from one row in google sheet?
For example, I want to do ARRAYFORMULA for MEDIAN formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MEDIAN(A2:A,$B$2,$C$2))
```

where

A2: start date - 2020-07-22 10:00 
B2: start hour - 8:00 
C2: end hour - 17:30

And the result of MEDIAN(A2:A,B2,C2) is 10:00, but ARRAYFORMULA does not work. (the result is 00:00:00)

 is it possible to make an Array for MEDIAN? Or is there any option to do that in other way?

Comment: What kind of range reference is `A2:A`? Is that a typo? Also, does A2 have a date AND time part? Please describe your data better.

Comment: MEDIAN is not supported under ARRAYFORMULA. have you considered to use average instead of median?

Comment: @teylyn i A2:A is typo. A2 have a date and time part. 2020-07-22 is a date, 10:00 is a time.

Comment: @player0 I didn't consider an average. So i will try to use it.

Comment: Adam, if I remember from your first question, for A2, you really only care about the time portion.  It is perhaps confusing here to include the date portion.  You had mod(A2,1), so you really want the MEDIAN, or AVERAGE, of three time values, don't you?  And ideally an ARRAYFORMULA so that it fills down the whole column...

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2):

Mean and median are not the same. Mean is essentially AVERAGE, while MEDIAN is the "middle-most" value in a set:

`=AVERAGE(2,1,9)` returns 4 [i.e., (1+2+9)/4 ]

`=MEDIAN(2,1,9)` returns 2 (i.e., the value in the middle if all the numbers were lined up from lowest to highest)

If you only have to compare three columns, you could get by with a sort of "brute force" value-to-value comparison array. For instance, in D2:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(((A2:A-INT(A2:A)<B2:B)*(A2:A-INT(A2:A)>C2:C))+((A2:A-INT(A2:A)>B2:B)*(A2:A-INT(A2:A)<C2:C)),A2:A-INT(A2:A),IF((B2:B<(A2:A-INT(A2:A))*(B2:B>C2:C))+(B2:B>(A2:A-INT(A2:A))*(B2:B<C2:C)),B2:B,C2:C)))
```

In English, this says:

"If the first value is lower than the second AND higher than the third, OR if the first value is higher than the second AND lower than the third, it is the median. Return the first value.

If neither of those is true, check to see if the second value is lower than the first AND higher than the third, OR if the second value is higher than the first AND lower than the third. If so, it is the median. Return the second value.

If nothing has been true so far, then the third value must be the median. Return the third value."

The one additional thing is you'll notice I have `E2:E-INT(E2:E)`. This gets rid of the date portion and leaves only the time, since in Google Sheets, dates are whole numbers while times are decimal portions less than 1. So removing the INTeger (i.e., whole) part of the cell value leaves only the decimal portion, which is the time. This is necessary so that the comparisons can be of-a-kind.

Answer (score 0):

arrayformula for average:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(N(A2:C*1)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(A2:A="",,
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")"))&"")), 
 "select Col2"), "hh:mm"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

arrayformula for `MEDIAN` now possible:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:C10, LAMBDA(xx, TEXT(MEDIAN(xx), "hh:mm"))))
```

[image]